# office-js - How to get the HtmlElement from a ClientResult

Tags: office-js, office-ui-fabric

I'm writing an MS Word add in, using office-js and office-ui-fabric-react.  One requirement is to search the document for certain text, show a dialog to the user asking a question, and then replace the text based on the response.

I can search the document using wildcards successfully, I can show a popup (teaching bubble or callout which both seem to be wrappers using the dialog API) successfully for a static button, but attaching a popup to the text that was found is the piece of the puzzle that I'm looking for.

A search returns a Word.RangeCollection, which is an array of Word.Range. The getHtml() method returns a OfficeExtension.ClientResult.  From that you can get the value which is just the text, but I need the actual HtmlElement.

Perhaps my approach is wrong.  I'm open to any alternative solutions.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "attaching a popup to the text". Could you clarify?

Comment: Clarification:  Let's say we are searching for the word "test".  The software would find the word test and create a dialog next to it that says "would you like to replace the word 'test' with 'test1'?".  Of course search and replace would do this but we are actually inserting mail merge tags and not actually looking for words.  We are using wildcards and looking for customer defined delimiters such as "<*>"

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a dialog *next to* the found word, I don't think there's any way to do that. As an alternative, I think you could probably have a function that highlights the found word and then has the "would you like …" prompt in the task pane. You could also have the prompt using the Dialog API, but you can't control where the dialog appears and it might cover the highlighted text.